# Constructing a tuple from a move only type with a std::function member

Tags: c++, stdtuple

please consider the code below:

```
struct no_copy {
int x_;
std::function<void()> f_;

template <typename F>
no_copy(int x, F&& f)
    : x_{ x }, f_{ std::forward<F>(f) } {};

no_copy(const no_copy&) = delete;
no_copy& operator= (const no_copy&)  = delete;

no_copy(no_copy&&) noexcept = default;
no_copy& operator= (no_copy&&) noexcept = default;
};

int main() {
auto nc = no_copy(1, []() {});
auto tuple_func = std::make_tuple(std::move(nc), 2);

return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to construct a tuple from a move-only type with a `std::funtion<void()>` member. Under Visual Studio 2017 this code doesn't compile:

```
 error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to '_Ttype'
 note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

If i make the copy constructor `= default` everything works fine. I know this is related to the `std::function`, but I'm not sure what is the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: MSVC 2017 is the buggiest MSVC of all time. Upgrade to 2019 asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently an implementation bug: there's no initializer list in your code at all, and current versions of all compilers [accept it](https://www.godbolt.org/z/erxK6a) (MSVC since v19.22).